# Magento 2 import product attribute type fixed product tax

Tags: magento2

How can i import a products with an attributes of type "Fixed Product Tax" ?

When i export a csv from the back office i don't have any attribute of type "Fixed Product Tax"

Comment: I have a same issue in 223. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you created a custom product attribute called "Fixed Product Tax" and you want to export all the products with that attribute.

To do so, please navigate to **Admin -> System -> Data Transfer -> Export**

Select:

> "Entity type" : **Product**
>
> "File Format" : **CSV**

You can exclude all the attributes you don't need and export the file.

---

I am not sure, but it might be the case that you added a new "Tax Class" with a new custom option of "Fixed Product Tax". Take a look under this attribute if you still can't find it.